# Add an element in a List<?>

Tags: java, generics, collections

I've created this:

```
List<?> result = new ArrayList<>();
```

I'm trying to do:

```
result.add("");
```

Java compiler tells:

> The method add(capture#9-of ?) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Any ideas? How could I solve it?

Comment: <? extends Object> why '<?>' ?

Comment: If you add a ``String``, why don't you declare your ``List`` as ``List<String>``?

Comment: Generics are for compile type safety checking. What type of list do you want here? Just use proper type to solve it. if you want to add all type of Objects in it then simply change it to `List<Object>`

Answer (score 3):

When having a `List<?>`, then `null` is the only reference you can add. So this should work:

```
 List<?> result = new ArrayList<>();
 result.add(null);
```

However, this is not allowed:

```
 result.add("");
```

The reason is that the compiler cannot be entirely sure if the reference you're trying to add, matches the unknown at compile-time wildcard (`?`) type.

In order to allow adding `String` references to the `List`, you should define it as:

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
result.add("");
```

Comment: Question: What is the difference between `List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();`  and `List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();`? As I understand, the `<String>` on the right sied of the assignment does not need to be there, but does it make a difference?

Comment: `new ArrayList<>()` is supported after Java7. It's an improvement in the compiler feature, called _type inference_, which is used to automatically detect the type-parameter (`String`), instead of asking you to explicitly provide it. Check [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074080/core-java/jdk-7--the-diamond-operator.html) for more info.

Comment: Ahh, thank you. So it does not make any difference except that it is shorter?

Comment: Yes, pretty much the motivation behind introducing this feature was simply the fact, that Java was criticized for being too verbose. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's important to note that `List<Object>` and `List<?>` are not the same. You can insert an Object, or any subtype of Object, into a `List<Object>`. But you can only insert `null` into a `List<?>`

The [unbounded wildcard type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html) is specified using the wildcard character (?), for example, `List<?>`. This is called a list of **unknown type**. There are two scenarios where an unbounded wildcard is a useful approach:

- If you are writing a method that can be implemented using functionality provided in the Object class.
- When the code is using methods in the generic class that don't depend on the type parameter. For example, `List.size` or `List.clear`. In fact, `Class<?>` is so often used because most of the methods in `Class<T>` do not depend on `T`.

---

Consider the following method, `printList`:

```
 public static void printList(List<Object> list) {
    for (Object elem : list)
        System.out.println(elem + " ");
    System.out.println();
 }
```

The goal of `printList` is to print a list of any type, but it fails to achieve that goal — it prints only a list of Object instances; it cannot print `List<Integer>`, `List<String>`, `List<Double>`, and so on, because they are not subtypes of `List<Object>`. To write a generic `printList` method, use `List<?>`:

```
public static void printList(List<?> list) {
   for (Object elem: list)
       System.out.print(elem + " ");
   System.out.println();
}
```

Because for any concrete type A, `List<A>` is a subtype of `List<?>`, you can use `printList` to print a list of any type:

```
List<Integer> li = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
List<String>  ls = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");
printList(li);
printList(ls);
```

Read more about it on [Oracle official documentation - Wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html)

Comment: besides, signature of `printList` may be `static <T> void printList(List<T> list)`

Comment: @SashaSalauyou yes you are correct, we can use `<T>` also in this case but here In this example I want to explain use of `<?>`

Answer (score 1):

`<?>`  It's called a `wildcard` type you can do somethng like this:

```
 List<SomeClass> result = new ArrayList<>();
```

SomeClass can be `String` or `another`.

Answer (score 0):

The generic type needs to be defined, e.g. when you want to add "" (String) than you can do it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    result.add("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you object is known only at the time of feed values into List then you can use given below code.

```
    public  <T>  void feedList(T value)
{
    List<T> genericList = new ArrayList<T>();
    genericList.add(value);

}
feedList("test");
```